# Was helium hydride really the first molecule?

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, elements

This press release by NASA: https://www.nasa.gov/feature/the-universe-s-first-type-of-molecule-is-found-at-last/

> When the universe was still very young, only a few kinds of atoms existed. Scientists believe that around 100,000 years after the big bang, helium and hydrogen combined to make a molecule called helium hydride for the first time. Helium hydride should be present in some parts of the modern universe, but it has never been detected in space — until now.

Naively I would expect that the first molecule to form would be the H$_2$. A claim that HeH$^+$ was before that should mean that it has larger binding energy that allowed the molecules to withstand more radiation. However, if I check Wikipedia for dissociation energies of these molecules, I see $436\,\rm kJ/mol$ for H$_2$ and $360 \,\rm kJ/mol$ for HeH$^+$.

Additionally, helium hydride is charged and should interact with lower energy photons that will destabilize the bond due to sheer quantity.

And finally, the temperature mentioned in the article is $4000\rm\, K \sim 0.34 \, eV$ — which is quite below the dissociation energy of molecular Hydrogen ($4.52 \,\rm eV$). Why was the formation of molecules delayed so much? Is this one of those situations where baryon-to-photon ratio is important and photons overwhelm the baryons?

Could someone please explain this situation?

Comment: See the question that has been closed as a duplicate for an alternative explanation.

Comment: @RobJeffries could you share the link please?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/530851/why-was-helium-hydride-ion-heh-not-hydrogen-h-2-the-first-molecule-forme?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @RobJeffries nice, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In "[Atomic and molecular processes in the early Universe](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-4075/35/10/201)" ([eprint](https://www.physast.uga.edu/uploads/phys8900_stancil/jpb02eu.pdf)) 2002, Lepp et al describe this process (emphasis mine):

> Molecular hydrogen was the first neutral molecule formed in the Universe and remains the most abundant. **Because it does not have a dipole moment, molecular hydrogen cannot form directly by a radiative process.** The most common reaction paths leading to H$_2$ formation in the early Universe use H$^+_2$ and H$^−$ as intermediaries....
>
> **The molecular ion HeH+ was the first to appear**...and so at the earliest times it is the first to produce H$_2$. The HeH$^+$ is first converted to the H$^+_2$ molecular ion and then to H$_2$ through the series of reactions
>
> \begin{align}
> \rm H^+  + He & \to \rm HeH^+ + \nu \\
> \rm HeH^+ + H & \to \rm H^+_2 + He \\
> \rm H^+_2 + H & \to \rm H_2 + H^+,
> \end{align}
>
> where both protons and He acted as catalyst, being returned to the gas once H$_2$ is formed to start the process again.

Comment: There is also a H + H$^{*}$ interaction that produces H$_2$.. The important point is that all these reaction routes to H$_2$ require hydrogen **atoms**.